# I am trying to edit the toplevel window for a project I am making

Tags: python, tkinter

we are supposed to make a login screen my issue is that I am not familiar with top level windows and I dont know how to put labels and buttons on it

This is the code that I am working with

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkthemes as th


class App(th.ThemedTk):

    def __init__(self, title: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.config(theme="adapta")

        self.hello_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Hello, World!")
        self.change_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Click Me", command=self.change_text)

        self.window = tk.Label(self,text="New Window")
        self.window = tk.Button(self, text="Click Me", command=self.change_text)

        self.initialize_widgets()

    def initialize_widgets(self):
        self.hello_label.pack()
        self.change_button.pack()

    def change_text(self):
        self.hello_label.config(text="I Changed!")
        self.window = tk.Toplevel(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App("Login")
    app.mainloop()
```

I though that I could type labels and commands under the init function but assign them to tk instead of ttk but it did not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the `Label` and `Button` to the new `Toplevel` that you create in `change_text`.  The first argument in the widget creation functions is the parent widget.  The `change_text` method below is amended to open a new `Toplevel` window and add the Label and Button to it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App( tk.Tk ):

    def __init__(self, title: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)

        self.hello_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Hello, World!")
        self.change_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Click Me", command=self.change_text)

        # Moved into change_text.
        # self.window = tk.Label(self,text="New Window")
        # self.window = tk.Button(self, text="Click Me", command=self.change_text)

        self.initialize_widgets()

    def initialize_widgets(self):
        self.hello_label.pack()
        self.change_button.pack()

    def change_text_tl( self ):
        self.tl_label.config( text = 'Now I changed too!')

    def change_text(self):
        self.hello_label.config(text="I Changed!")
        self.window = tk.Toplevel(self)
        #                           parent       kwargs ->
        self.tl_label  =  tk.Label( self.window, text="New Window")
        self.tl_button = tk.Button( self.window, text="Click Me", 
                                    command=self.change_text_tl)
        self.tl_label.pack()
        self.tl_button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App("Login")
    app.mainloop()
```